# Raleigh Twenty front wheel removal

Tags: wheels

I'm trying to change the tires on a c. 1971 Raleigh Twenty, and I cannot for the life of me get the front wheel off: nuts are loosened, dynamo/basket support/mudguards all disengaged, but it won't come out: what am I missing?

Comment: Is the axle loose, and the wheel hanging up on something else? or is the axle refusing to come loose from the dropouts?

Comment: I believe it may have retention washers either inside or outside the dropouts. If inside you may have to slightly spread the fork blades apart.

Comment: Post a picture.  But the most likely case is that there are washers on the axles with "fingers" that stick into holes in the fork.

Comment: Has th ebike been crashed?  The fork blades may be slightly compressed holding the wheel in place.  Also look for burrs acting as lawyer lips.

Comment: The axle is refusing to come loose from the drop-outs. I'll investigate for retention washers, & see if I can spread the forks slightly. I had no such problem changing the back tire, though.

Comment: You've not said how much you've tried to wobble/work the wheel to release it - if not a lot, then wobble/rock it sideways a bit more and see if that goves an indication of where the resistance is. If it seems like parts have seized up then a bit of WD40 won't do any harm. Just apply it carefully so that it doesn't wash out the grease in your wheel bearings - unless you are regreasing the bearings at the same time which might be worth it.